# How am I going to get the correct formula structure to get the side c in my program C++?

Tags: c++

I made a program on how to get the side `c` of a triangle. The program works but the calculations is somehow wrong. I was trying to input `a = 5`, `b = 5`, and the Angle `C = 90`. The answer was `8.50904`, but based on google, the answer should be `7.07`. I am using C++ btw and Dev C++.

```
float a, b, c, C, Angle;

cout << "Enter the value of side a: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter the value of side b: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Enter the value of angle C: ";
cin >> C;

Angle = cos(C);

c=sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2) - (2 * (a * b) * Angle));

cout << "The value of side c is " << c;
return 0;
```

Comment: Try with type `double`, and have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: It is still the same

Comment: The angle is in degrees or radians?

Comment: The angle should be degrees. Should I specify it? How do I do it?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cos Note the paragraph about parameters. Remember that radians = degrees * Pi / 180.

Answer (score 2):

Function `cos`'s input angle is in radian and the result of `cos(90)` when `C = 90 rad`, is about `-0.4480`.

So with this angle, the result of `c` is `8.50904` and it's correct.

You should convert your input angle from degree to radian in order to get correct output.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood most of the people here. I was putting 90 degrees for Angle C. Side a is missing, the user have to input the side b, c and Angle C in order to get the side c.

Comment: @Richard Are you sure? "_the user have to input the side b, c and Angle C in order to get the side c_"; Then you'll calculate side `c` that is an input?!

Comment: No, C and c are different. C is for Angle and c is for the side. The program needs to calculate the side c, while the user have to input the value of side b,a and Angle C. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Richard Anyways, I'd suggest to split your program into little [functions](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dbJAG4g4FeQjomSb), to ease the development and the testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is wrong. If you want to calculate the hypotenuse (opposite the 90 degree angle):

```
H = sqrt ((a * a) + (b * b));
H = sqrt(25 + 25);
H = 7.07;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not calculating the calculus. This is the law of cosine if I am correct. The program have to get the c, while the user have to input the value of side b, c, and the Angle C.

Comment: ("get the c, while the user have to input the value of side b, c,"): Did you mean 'a'?? And remember: The cos(90 DEGREES) = 0!!!!! https://essaseoutras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/tabela-trigonometrica.jpg

Comment: https://www.calculat.org/pt/area-perimetro/obr/oo-pt-1.svg /  https://www.calculat.org/pt/area-perimetro/form/oo-pt-1.svg